# C++ Passing argument into main function with multiple exclamation points

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I have the following c++ code, which prints the input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Input:" << argv[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For an input consisting of only characters it works fine. However, when the input has multiple exclamation points, it does not. 
For example, I called my program "test". When I try to run the program in the terminal with "./test Hello!!" it prints:

> ./test Hello./test Hello!
>   Input:Hello./test

When I use 3 exclamation points "./test Hello!!!", it prints:

> -bash: !: event not found

My questions are:
1. Why is it not printing "Input:Hello!!" and "Input:Hello!!!"?
2. How can this be fixed for any input with multiple exclamation points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most shells the `!` is a special character. It tells the shell to run a command from your history (see the manpage for full details). You'll need to escape the `!` or use single ticks like:

```
./test 'Hello!!!'
```